# Tkinter - How can I delete the bold text and the focus in the ComboBox widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

To defocus the ComboBox widgets, I use the "Defocus" custom function written in my example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def Defocus(event):
    event.widget.master.focus_set()

parent=Tk()
parent.geometry("530x280+370+100")
parent.title("TEST")
parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
parent.minsize(485, 280)

SV=StringVar()
SV.set("I hate to see the bold text..")
MenuComboBox=ttk.Combobox(parent, state="readonly", values=("I hate to see the bold text..", "ciao", "hola", "hello"), textvariable=SV, width=50)
MenuComboBox.bind("<FocusIn>", Defocus)
MenuComboBox.place(x=20, y=20)

SV2=StringVar()
SV2.set("I hate to see the bold text..")
MenuComboBox2=ttk.Combobox(parent, state="readonly", values=("I hate to see the bold text..", "ciao", "hola", "hello"), textvariable=SV2, width=50)
MenuComboBox2.bind("<FocusIn>", Defocus)
MenuComboBox2.place(x=20, y=60)

parent.mainloop()
```

it works but not at all, it has a "bad behaviour" for my point of view. the text in the ComboBox widgets became bold and I don't like it (see my attached GIF). I have two questions:

1. how can I improve my custom "Defocus" function to take off the "bold option" in the ComboBox widgets?
2. is there a way to change the default style of the ComboBox widgets to delete the focus and the bold text options? in this way, I can avoid to use my custom function every times I have to use a ComboBox widget.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Combobox uses bold text whenever it's entry is focused. So a  solution would be to use, another entry and shift focus towards it.
So i created a dummy Entry called `dump`.this dump is hidden through `place_forget()`.
How to shift focus?
for that run this steps whenever a item is selected `<<ComboboxSelected>>`

- focus the root window (`parent.focus()`)
- type something in the entry (`set()`)
- focus it (`focus()`)
- select it  `select_range()`

To know the difference i have included Normal Combobox `MenuComboBox2`

```
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import *
class CBox(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,variable):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.SV=variable
        self.Box=Combobox(self,state="readonly", values=("I hate to see the bold text..", "ciao", "hola", "hello"), textvariable=self.SV, width=50)
        self.Box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.doThat)
        self.fvar=StringVar()
        self.fake=Entry(self,text='test',textvariable=self.fvar)
        self.arrange()
    def arrange(self):
        self.Box.pack()
        self.fake.pack()
        self.fake.pack_forget()
    def doThat(self,*args):
        self.focus()
        self.fvar.set('Hello')
        self.fake.focus()
        self.fake.select_range(0,'end')
root=Tk()
SV=StringVar()
def Defocus(event):
    event.widget.master.focus_set()
diff=Combobox(root,state="readonly", values=("I hate to see the bold text..", "ciao", "hola", "hello"), width=50)
diff.pack()
diff.bind("<FocusIn>", Defocus)
a=CBox(root,SV)
a.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Edit:** Now it doesn't depend on the parent element. (refer to that `CBox` alone)

Comment: it's a workaround but.. it works, thanks RahulARange! in my real software I have a lot of TopLevel windows. so, to improve your  `selected` custom function, I suggest to replace the `parent.focus()` instruction with `event.widget.master.focus_set()` and add the `event` option, otherwise whenever the user uses a ComboBox widget in a TopLevel window, he will be redirect to the parent one and it's not a good behaviour.

Comment: @TurboC now I made a custom class which doesn't depend on parent widget for focus things